# How to make files created by an application readable from computer?

Tags: android

I am not being able to create an image that is public. I tried to create it in public pictures directory and it gets created there and I can view it from my file explorer in the phone. But the picture is neither picked up by default albums app nor I can see it by connecting the phone to computer. so I suppose the picture is still private. What I require is that the picture must be copied to the computer. Here is the code snippet.

```
            String photoPath = "sdcard/test.jpg";
            Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
            squareBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap,0,0,1000,1000);
            dvBitmap = squareBitmap.createScaledBitmap(squareBitmap,200,200,false);

            //saving bitmap to JPEG in sd card
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            dvBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bytes);
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            File f = new File(path,"output.jpg");
            f.setReadable(true);
            try {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"CREATING FILE");
                f.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"FILE CREATED");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"CANNOT CREATE FILE");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: The phone I was testing was Sony Xperia S. Now I tested on another phone which is Samsung and same code works well. Both are tested on internal storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was MediaScannerConnection has indexed them. Just adding the following code after the file creating did the trick.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                        new String[]{f.toString()}, null,null);
```